# Multiple Android application instances

Tags: android, runtime, multiple-instances

Is it possible to install or run multiple instances of the same application? And is it possible to create a second instance of an application within the application? This way I know whether or not it is acceptable to make use of things like `static Context`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application specifies a different package (com.app_a) vs (com.app_b) you can run one application more than once, but this becomes a new application due to its newly specified package.

Short answer: no. When you run your app anew it will be replaced.

There is however the ability to run multiple tasks for one application that consist of a collection of activities. To read more on this see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 0):

No, only a single install per package

Comment: And what about the multiple instances through the application? Is that possible?

Comment: Sort of : you can define your components to run in different processes and they won't see the same static classes but that's really an exception to the rule